# Access/Use default flow methods

Tags: origen-sdk

We have test interface created that we use with all our origen flows that has test flow methods defined. I believe there's possibly an issue with our test methods and to debug I'd like to use the default `func` method rather than the one defined in our interface.

Where would I find this method and what is the correct way to integrate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func` is not a flow method provided by Origen, rather it is a method that is commonly used in examples to indicate the notion of "a functional test".

The underlying API provided by Origen is `flow.test(test_object, options)`, and within most test program source code the `flow` will be inferred, so often you will see code that simply calls `test`.

The test object can be just a name, or it can be an object representing the test like a [TestInstance](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/j750/#Creating_a_Test_Instance) or [TestSuite](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/#Creating_a_Test_Suite) object provided by the Teradyne and Advantest APIs respectively.

You can create a test program flow (and documentation for it) by using only the `test` method, you can see examples of that in the source code for this video on how to create test program flows: http://origen-sdk.org/origen/videos/5-create-program-flow/

A test program however, is comprised of more than just a flow, and you would normally also want the other files that define what the test is to be generated in addition to the flow.

In time, we hope that the Origen community will produce libraries of off-the-shelf methods like `func` which would generate the complete test as well as inserting into the flow, currently though it is the application's responsibility to create such methods within their test program interface.

See this example source code for how to create a `func` method that can target multiple tester types - http://origen-sdk.org/origen/videos/6-create-program-tests/

To start with, you shouldn't worry about the multiple tester aspect, just refer to this guide for the APIs that are available to generate the test program artefacts for creating tests on the V93K - http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/